Rebinding y-n-a-q-?-queries
I'd like to remap the keys used in responses to y-n-a-q-? queries like Recursively delete folder? (y, n, a, q, ?). I know that one can remap y-or-n queries by modifying the query-replace-map and I've already done that, but it seems a different map is used of y-n-a-q-? queries, yet when I use C-h m to find out the active modes when such a query is asked I don't find any special ones whose maps I'd need to modify. Which map is used for those queries?

That's hardwired in dired-delete-file. AFAIK, there is no keymap that you can surgically change for just this case.
